# Unexpected result when sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I use this code for sorting:

```
var fileEntries = from f in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
                  let fi = new FileInfo(f) 
                  orderby fi.Name 
                  select fi.FullName;
```

There is some thing wrong When i put Face10, Face11 first it take face1 after it take Face10 so this is the problem

This is the Output I want

```
[0] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFace/1\ 1.bmp"
[1] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/2\ 2.bmp"
[2] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/3\ 3.bmp"
[3] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/4\ 4.bmp"
[4] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/4\ 9.bmp"
[5] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/4\ 10.bmp"
```

But it gives

```
[0] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFace/1\ 1.bmp"
[5] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/4\ 10.bmp"
[1] = "N:\FaceRecProOV - Copy (2)\FaceRecProOV\bin\Debug/TrainedFaces/2\ 2.bmp"
```

What is wrong in the Code???

Answer (score 2):

It's doing that because it is sorting it assuming it is a string ("10" comes before "2.").

You will have to grab the filename and convert it to an int and sort based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the data alphabetically, rather than numerically.  Assuming that the input can't be modified at all you will need to parse the file names into numbers and then sort on that.

```
var fileEntries = from f in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
let fi = new FileInfo(f) 
orderby parse(fi.Name )
select fi.FullName;

public static int Parse(string filename)
{
  //for your real program you'll want to ensure that there is error handling and determine what to do with non-numeric filenames.
  return int.Parse(filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                           .Select(f=>new FileInfo(f))
                           .OrderNaturallyBy(fi=>fi.Name)
                           .Select(fi=>fi.FullName);


public static class S_O_Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderNaturallyBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,string> selector)
    {
        return list.Select(item => new
                    {
                        t = item,
                        tempstr = Regex.Replace(selector(item), @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(20, '0'))
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.tempstr)
                    .Select(x => x.t);
    }
}
```